# align ⌄show more vertically

Tags: html, css

I have this code:

```
<a ...>⌄show more</a>
```

Unfortunately the chevron character `⌄` does not alignwell with the text, it is supposed to be a bit higher. What is the proper way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

To align the chevron character `⌄` with the text, you need to wrap it with a element and apply `display: flex;` with `align-items: center;` to its parent element, in this case `<a>` tag.

```css
.link {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<a class="link">
  <span class="sym">⌄</span>show more
</a>
```

If you want to align more precisely, you need to use `transform` property to position the symbol along with the text, like this

```css
.link .sym {
  display: inline-block;
  transform: translateY(-10%) rotateX(45deg);
}
```

```html
<a class="link">
  <span class="sym">⌄</span>show more
</a>
```